# How do I get position.bin from ngraph.native?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, graph

I'm using [ngraph](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph) family libraries to build some graphs in browser.

I've tried to run layout using [ngraph.native](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.native) but all that I get is ~10k .bin files without position.bin.

Am I missing something? What should I do after I get all those .bin files?

Here's what I tried:

- creating graph in node.js
- converting graph to binary using [ngraph.tobinary](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.tobinary)
- exporting links.bin to ngraph.native
- executing command `layout++ links.bin`

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Guess I figured out how to get positions.bin

I took a look at ngraph.offline.layout source and found that positions.bin is created after all iterations are completed.

So. Here are my changes that helped to get positions.bin (all changes made in file main.cpp (ngraph.native/demo/gcc/main.cpp):

- in `void save()` change first param type from int to string
- in `int main()` at the bottom inside last for-loop change `save(i, graphLayout.getBodies());` to `save(to_string(i), graphLayout.getBodies());`
- in `int main()` at the bottom after last for-loop add `save("positions", graphLayout.getBodies());`

That's it.

Comment: great, had same issue and this helped. Thanks for sharing the solution.